# dnscrypt-proxy takes long to start at boot

Tags: boot, networking, dns, proxy, systemd

SystemD-analyze blame shows 21s.

The issue seems to be here:

```
sudo systemctl status dnscrypt-proxy  
Sep 30 22:18:22 HorniSlezsko systemd[1]: Listening on dnscrypt-proxy listening socket.  
Sep 30 22:18:24 HorniSlezsko dnscrypt-proxy[1036]: [INFO] + DNS Security Extensions are supported  
Sep 30 22:18:24 HorniSlezsko dnscrypt-proxy[1036]: [INFO] + Namecoin domains can be resolved  
Sep 30 22:18:24 HorniSlezsko dnscrypt-proxy[1036]: [INFO] + Provider supposedly doesn't keep logs  
Sep 30 22:18:24 HorniSlezsko dnscrypt-proxy[1036]: [NOTICE] Starting dnscrypt-proxy 1.6.1  
Sep 30 22:18:24 HorniSlezsko dnscrypt-proxy[1036]: [INFO] Generating a new session key pair
Sep 30 22:18:24 HorniSlezsko dnscrypt-proxy[1036]: [INFO] Done  
Sep 30 22:18:39 HorniSlezsko dnscrypt-proxy[1036]: [ERROR] Unable to retrieve server certificates  
Sep 30 22:18:40 HorniSlezsko dnscrypt-proxy[1036]: [INFO] Refetching server certificates  
Sep 30 22:18:45 HorniSlezsko dnscrypt-proxy[1036]: [INFO] Server certificate #808464433 received
```

It can never connect at first and always does so succesfully 15s later.
Only change I've made is in `/lib/systemd/system/dnscrypt-proxy.service`, in this line:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dnscrypt-proxy \
    --resolver-name=soltysiak
```

I've tried various resolvers and same issue.

Comment: This is over my head but to help others who know the subject, why did you need to change DNS proxy server whatever in the first place? Perhaps there is a different method. Please update your question with an introduction on why DNS stuff had to be messed with in the first place.

Comment: That's a long story: https://www.opendns.com/about/innovations/dnscrypt/ 

"In the same way the SSL turns HTTP web traffic into HTTPS encrypted Web traffic, DNSCrypt turns regular DNS traffic into encrypted DNS traffic that is secure from eavesdropping and man-in-the-middle attacks."

Though the why is rather unimportant here. The problem is boot related

Comment: Like I said, way over my head. I up-voted your question so hopefully others more informed take notice. I took the liberty of adding tags for `DNS`, `Proxy` and `Encryption` so experts following those tags will notice your question. You can change them by editing your question if inappropriate. Sorry to say it's all I can do to help.

Comment: @otso I've had issues with dnscrypt-proxy starting up with systemd in the past. Ultimately, I stopped systemd from running it at boot by entering `sudo systemctl disable dnscrypt-proxy.service && sudo systemctl disable dnscrypt-proxy-resolvconf.service` in a terminal. I prefer placing my dnscrypt commands in `/etc/rc.local`, because I find it more reliable. In your case, however, you may wish to first try a different resolver to eliminate the possibility that your resolver is causing this problem.

Comment: I stated in the op that I had tried multiple resolvers, same issue everywhere because the problem isn't that it can't connect with the resolver at all but that it can't do so at first. It's as if the network was delayed. I tried putting the thing into rc.local and same issue, only now it's rc-local.service that takes a lot of time to start but thanks for the idea anyway!